# Pandas combine two dataframes to update values of a particular column in 1st dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 :
    A     B     C
0   a0    b0    c0
1   a1    b1    c1
2   a2    b2    c2
3   a3    b3    c3
4   a4    b4    c4

df2 :
    A     B     C
0   a0    b0    c11
1   a1    b1    c5
2   a70   b2    c20
3   a3    b9    c9
```

In df1, for every row, whenever Column A and Column B values are equal to values in df2, column C should be updated with value from df2.

```
Output:
    A     B     C
0   a0    b0    c11
1   a1    b1    c5
2   a2    b2    c2
3   a3    b3    c3
4   a4    b4    c4
```

I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
df1.set_index(['A', 'B'])
df2.set_index(['A', 'B'])
df1.update(df2)
df1.reset_index()
df2.reset_index()
```

Comment: what about the last row? u ignore it?

Comment: Your solution is right. You need to assign to `df1` and `df2`, when setting the index. From your code above, it seems that you did not. I will delete my answer, because it is not needed. You got the solution right.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1["C"][:4] = np.where((df1["A"][:4]==df2["A"])&(df1["B"][:4]==df2["B"]),df2["C"],df1["C"][:4])


    A   B   C
0   a0  b0  c11
1   a1  b1  c5
2   a2  b2  c2
3   a3  b3  c3
4   a4  b4  c4
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck once the OP answers i will be more than happy to explain everything